# asp.net core 2.1 odata use different name of entity in the route

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I have a long name of of entity in my code EmployeTraining which used as entity in OData and with same name for the controller.

```
Startup.cs

 app.UseMvc(routeBuilder=>
        {                
            routeBuilder.Expand().Select().Count().OrderBy().Filter().MaxTop(null);
            routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("EmployeTraining", "odata/v1", EdmModelBuilder.GetEdmModelEmploye());

        });


EdmModelBuilder.cs

public static IEdmModel GetEdmModelEmployes()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<EmployeTraining>("EmployeTraining");            
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }

EmployeTrainingControllers.cs

public class EmployeTrainingController : ODataController
{
    internal IEmployeService ServiceEmploye { get; set; }

    public EmployesController(IEmployeService serviceEmploye)
    {

        ServiceEmploye = serviceEmploye;
    }

    //// GET api/employes
    [HttpGet]
    [MyCustomQueryable()]
    public IQueryable<EmployeTraining> Get()
    {

        return ServiceEmploye.GetListeEmployes();
    }
}
```

To call my service it works only through this URL: https://{server}/odata/v1/rh/employetraining

but I need to  use this https://{server}/odata/v1/rh/employe-training
any help please.

Comment: I tried but did not work

Comment: How did you define `[MyCustomQueryable()]`?Also,your request url contains `rh`,but I could not see anything you define for the route attribute or route template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such scenario,change like below:

1.Change the entityset name:

```
public static class EdmModelBuilder
{
    public static IEdmModel GetEdmModelEmployes()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<EmployeTraining>("employe-training");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

2.Add the attribute:

```
public class EmployeTrainingController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("employe-training")]
    //[MyCustomQueryable()]
    public IQueryable<EmployeTraining> Get()
    {

         return ServiceEmploye.GetListeEmployes();
    }
}
```

3.Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder=>
{                
     routeBuilder.Expand().Select().Count().OrderBy().Filter().MaxTop(null);
     routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("EmployeTraining", "odata/v1/rh", EdmModelBuilder.GetEdmModelEmploye());

});
```

Request the url:`https://{server}/odata/v1/rh/employe-training`

Comment: Hi @Rena. can you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62157807/asp-net-core-2-1-odata-how-to-omit-odata-type-in-response

Answer (score 0):

The Reason why is working using `https://{server}/odata/v1/rh/employetraining` is because is the `Get` method of the `EmployeTrainingController` Controller.

You should be able to change that behaibour if you modify the `[HttpGet]` on the `Get` method to `[HttpGet("employe-training")]`

Comment: try to change it for `[HttpGet("odata/v1/rh/employe-training")]` if that works, then we will need to have a look at the routing.